# How can I use the first function as a closure to the second function

Tags: swift, closures

I have got an assignment to use first function

```
func printValue(boolValue: Bool) {
print(boolValue)
}
```

as a closure to the second

```
func calculate(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
completion(printValue(boolValue: 2>1))
}
```

Could you give me a piece of advice on how can I do it? As I understand, if we use the first func as an argument to the second function, it will already count as a closure. In that case I should return Void value in the first function, right?

Comment: Unclear what the question means. Do you mean `calculate(completion:printValue)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
func printValue(boolValue: Bool) {
    print(boolValue)
}

func calculate(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    completion(2 > 1)
}

calculate(completion: printValue)
```

In your code, `printValue(boolValue: 2 > 1)` is not a function, it is the return value of `printValue(boolValue:)` when fed the condition `2 > 1`. Whereas, `calculate(completion:)` takes as an argument *another* function which has the signature `(Bool) -> Void)`. Inside `calculate(completion:)` that function is called `completion`.